# How to query the multiple values at a time in entity framework?

Tags: entity-framework-4

my request:
"http://hostname/sample/getrecord?appid=1&domain=physics,chemistry&platform=cs,ece"

How to query in linq to sql  like "IN" statement in sqlserver 2008.
How to send multiple parameters of same column as string to SP in linq to sql.
Please help me out....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you want something like:

```cs
string domain = "physics,chemistry";
string[] domains = domain.Split(',');

var records = context.Records.Where(r => domains.Contains(r.Domain)).ToList();
```

(assuming that `Domain` is a `string` property in entity `Record`)